# Htaccess file redirect to public folder but the api folder is before

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am coming to you because I need your help. I told my .htaccess file that the default folder is "public" but since I did that, the API which is before this folder, requests no longer works and I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you for your help.

```
- app (my api...)
- public
- .htaccess
```

Here is the configuration of the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the rewrite before the public.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/((?s).*)$ /app/$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```